# Video converted to FLV using FFMPEG gets 0 size

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert avi file to flv format using FFMPEG on server, but its giving me problems. On conversion, the file is converted to flv format but no data (0 kb size file). Tried debugging the code but could not. The FFMPEG is installed in CentOS, in path /usr/bin/ffmpeg, and i'm using following command for conversion:

```
$srcFile = "/home/mydomain/public_html/demo/test/sample.avi";
$destFile = "/home/mydomain/public_html/demo/test/sample_again.flv";

$ffmpegPath = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg";
$flvtool2Path = "/usr/local/bin/flvtool2";

$command = $ffmpegPath . " -y -i " . $srcFile .  " -ar 32000 -ab 32000 -f flv -s 320x240 ".
$destFile . " | " . $flvtool2Path . " -U stdin " . $destFile;

exec($command, $output);
print_r($output);
```

I tried doing:

```
exec("which ffmpeg");
```

And it gave me the path /usr/bin/ffmpeg, but get following error when i execute the code:

```
Array ( 
[0] => ERROR: undefined method `timestamp' for nil:NilClass 
[1] => ERROR: /usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/flv/stream.rb:285:in `lasttimestamp' 
[2] => ERROR: /usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/flv/stream.rb:274:in `duration' 
[3] => ERROR: /usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/flvtool2/base.rb:181:in `add_meta_data_tag' 
[4] => ERROR: /usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/flvtool2/base.rb:137:in `update' 
[5] => ERROR: /usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/flvtool2/base.rb:47:in `send' 
[6] => ERROR: /usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/flvtool2/base.rb:47:in `execute!' 
[7] => ERROR: /usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/flvtool2/base.rb:46:in `each' 
[8] => ERROR: /usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/flvtool2/base.rb:46:in `execute!' 
[9] => ERROR: /usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/flvtool2/base.rb:206:in `process_files' 
[10] => ERROR: /usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/flvtool2/base.rb:44:in `execute!' 
[11] => ERROR: /usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/flvtool2.rb:168:in `execute!' 
[12] => ERROR: /usr/local/cpffmpeg/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/flvtool2.rb:228 
[13] => ERROR: /usr/local/bin/flvtool2:2:in `require' 
[14] => ERROR: /usr/local/bin/flvtool2:2 
)
```

What could be the problem. Is this the problem of Flvtool2, if yes then what is it. Please suggest something

Comment: Does the command run straight from the command line

Comment: No, i'm executing php file from browser

Comment: anyone any solution, its not working at all

Comment: I meant have you tried testing it from the directly from the command line, so you can make sure it is not a problem with the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you var_dump($command) then run that command in the shell (as the user that apache is running under) ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like anything's actually going through the pipe.  Your ffmpeg command line specifies an actual output file instead of `-` (*i.e.*, STDOUT), so ffmpeg is writing the video to a file and then flvtool is trying to read from STDIN, which doesn't have the video.